# how to detect key combinations Such as Shift + (0-9,A-Z,a-z,Symbols) outside form in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard, keypress, keyup

i want to know whether user is typing using the shift key still pressed or not and log that like (Shift + T + R + Y).
i am not able to do so.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: [Please see here the file Form1.cs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gq1fVL3H6-IhNyOjvzHfGC6ES7ri_ZFm?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in Your **Keydown event**

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
{
    // This code will only be triggered when shift is pressed along with any other key.
}
```